# react-native-shadow-cards, why is my text pushing outside of the card?

Tags: react-native

I have the following basic card (https://github.com/Aamirali86/react-native-shadow-cards?ref=morioh.com&utm_source=morioh.com) being included on the page and the text is showing outside of the card. What can I do to make it show inside of it i.e. the card to expand with the contents?

```
import { Text, View } from "react-native";

import { Card } from "react-native-shadow-cards";
import PostResponseModel from "../../APILibrary/Models/Post/PostResponseModel";
import React from "react";

export default function ViewPost(props: { post: PostResponseModel }) {
  return (
    <Card style={{ padding: 10, margin: 10 }}>
      <Text style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>Subject</Text>
      <Text>Body</Text>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

I've tried React Native Elements Card instead but I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that because it was inside of a tabview body that the tabview needed at least a minHeight and it started working as expected